# NullReferenceException when Linq'ing IEnumerable<XElement>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, nullreferenceexception

I'm new to the whole Linq game, so please forgive my ignorance.

I have this piece of code here:

```
String tag = "Covers";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
IEnumerable<XElement> allDvds = doc.Element("Collection").Elements("DVD");
IEnumerable<XElement> filteredDvds = allDvds.Where(dvd => dvd.Element("Locks").Element(tag).Value == "true");
var dvdInfos = filteredDvds.Select(dvd => new
            {
                Name = dvd.Element("Title").Value,
                UPC = dvd.Element("UPC").Value,
                ID = dvd.Element("ID").Value,
            }
        );
foreach (var dvdInfo in dvdInfos)
{
    //...
}
```

As long as tag has a valid value, everything's peachy. But if tag has a value that's not a tag in the XML, I get a NullReferenceException when he tries to start the foreach loop.

I tried `if (dvdInfos.Count() > 0)` but then I get the NRE there.

I also tried `if (filteredDvds.Count() > 0)` but again NRE.

Any advise? Or is the only way to actually catch the NRE and proceed from there?

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<Collection>
  <DVD>
    <ProfileTimestamp>2012-12-08T17:39:16.000Z</ProfileTimestamp>
    <ID>4030521726802.5</ID>
    <UPC>4-030521-726802</UPC>
    <Title>The Amazing Spider-Man</Title>
<!-- ... -->
    <Locks>
      <Entire>false</Entire>
      <Covers>false</Covers>
      <Title>true</Title>
      <MediaType>true</MediaType>
      <Overview>false</Overview>
      <Regions>false</Regions>
      <Genres>true</Genres>
      <SRP>true</SRP>
      <Studios>true</Studios>
      <DiscInformation>true</DiscInformation>
      <Cast>true</Cast>
      <Crew>true</Crew>
      <Features>false</Features>
      <AudioTracks>false</AudioTracks>
      <Subtitles>false</Subtitles>
      <EasterEggs>false</EasterEggs>
      <RunningTime>false</RunningTime>
      <ReleaseDate>true</ReleaseDate>
      <ProductionYear>false</ProductionYear>
      <CaseType>false</CaseType>
      <VideoFormats>false</VideoFormats>
      <Rating>false</Rating>
    </Locks>
  </DVD>
</Collection>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with sample xml?

Comment: You're wrong about where the NRE is occurring.  `dvdInfos` cannot be null, you are getting it on one of these: `dvd.Element("xxx")`

Comment: Can you please post your sample xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using another Where clause instead of .Element(tag).Value. You are getting a nullreferenceexception because you are not using a linq query on that element and accessing it directly.

Try something like this:

```
String tag = "Covers";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
IEnumerable<XElement> allDvds = doc.Element("Collection").Elements("DVD");
IEnumerable<XElement> filteredDvds = allDvds.Where(
  dvd => dvd.Element("Locks") != null && 
  dvd.Element("Locks").Element(tag) != null && 
  dvd.Element("Locks").Element(tag).Value == "true");

var dvdInfos = filteredDvds.Select(dvd => new
        {
            Name = dvd.Element("Title").Value,
            UPC = dvd.Element("UPC").Value,
            ID = dvd.Element("ID").Value,
        }
    );
```

Comment: Updated answer. Because <Covers> may not exist you need to add it to the where clause.